# CPU Schedulers Offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sp-blitz

I logged onto a new clients systems and ran sp_blitz to see what's shaking. It reports back that "[CPU Schedulers Offline](http://BrentOzar.com/go/schedulers)" which is a new one for me.

> Some CPU cores are not accessible to SQL Server due to affinity masking or licensing problems.

Fair enough, I run the base query

```
SELECT
    DOS.is_online
,   DOS.status
,   DOS.*
FROM
    sys.dm_os_schedulers AS DOS
ORDER BY
    1;
```

That reports back that I have 8 set to VISIBLE OFFLINE, 43 to online. To my knowledge, no one at this client would have intentionally set any CPU affinity.

I decided to see if I could unbugger it. When I look at the properties window, I see 40 processors available and none of them set to have affinity.

[image]

Why there's 40 showing yet 43 entries in the dm_os_schedulers where is_online is true seems curious as well. The cpu_id of the 8 offline are 32 to 39.

sys.configurations seems to concur with affinity not being explicitly on

```
name                 value  value_in_use  description
affinity I/O mask    0      0             affinity I/O mask
affinity mask        0      0             affinity mask
affinity64 I/O mask  0      0             affinity64 I/O mask
affinity64 mask      0      0             affinity64 mask
```

This isn't an Enterprise Edition so the CAL grandfather thing *shouldn't* be factor here but I can ask that question tomorrow if need be

```
ProductVersion  ProductLevel  ProductUpdateLevel  Edition
11.0.5058.0     SP2           NULL                Standard Edition (64-bit)
```

Running Glenn Berry's diagnostic queries, this stuff might be relevant

- System Manufacturer: 'Dell Inc.', System Model: 'PowerEdge R720'.
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz

So, what gives? Am I virtualized and don't know it? Is there some other place I should be looking to determine why SQL Server can't use some of the CPUs?

### Reference articles

A list of articles I read but clearly didn't comprehend well enough to answer my own question

- BOL [sys.dm_os_schedulers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177526.aspx)
- [Glenn Berry's DMV a day](https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/a-dmv-a-day-%E2%80%93-day-9/)
- [SQLServerGeeks DMV a day](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sys-dm_os_schedulers/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you see makes perfect sense given the information available.

SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition is limited to the lesser of 4 sockets or 16 physical cores.

Since you have 40 cores (likely 2 socket 10 core + HT) 16 physical cores is going to be 32 logical cores (because of HT). If you have 40 total, I would EXPECT 8 to be VISIBLE OFFLINE due to licensing.

[Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012 - Cross-Box Scale Limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx#CrossBoxScale)

Edit: Additional Information

Depending on the OS involved the schedules may be bound to CPUs that are also making an unbalanced NUMA memory configuration for your system. While it is *highly* unlikely that this will cause you any issues (since it wasn't noticed that all the CPUs were being used in the first place) it could have a much higher impact on a highly used system where the foreign memory access can really add up.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but thought I would add.

It seems (at least in some cases) Enterprise Edition limits the number of cores to 40.

[SQL Server not using all CPU cores/threads](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49930/sql-server-not-using-all-cpu-cores-threads)

https://serverfault.com/questions/395525/what-is-sql-server-core-edition